# Is context a reserved keyword in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react-redux application. In one of the components, I was passing a prop 'context' with string value to indicate src of the component. I started seeing errors like Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

I was surprised as it was working previously and the only change I did was adding the extra prop. After I changed the prop name to 'src', the error disappeared. For confirmation, I again changed the prop to 'context' and it failed again.

Can anyone tell why this is a issue?

The component looks like this-

```
<SampleEditor text={text} context={'overview'}/>
```

[image: Console error]

Comment: It's not a reserved word. Can you post the code for the component SampleEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Redux v6 I think you can pass custom context to connect functions.
I had the same issue and I had no issue before with the keyword, but since I upgrade to the last version, I started having this issue.

You can check here : https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1177